# TealScript - arc4 Transaction parameter either Pay or Asset transfer

Tags: algorand, tealscript

is it possible to have multiple types of incomming transactions as arc4 parameter for the method?

```
  addLiquidity(
    aXfer: AssetTransferTxn | PayTxn,
    bXfer: AssetTransferTxn | PayTxn,
    poolAsset: AssetID,
    aAsset: AssetID,
    bAsset: AssetID
  ): void {
```

What is the best way to check if the transaction is asset transfer or pay tx?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the more general type `Txn` and then check whether it is an `AssetTransferTxn` or a `PayTxn` within the method.

```
  addLiquidity(
    aXfer: Txn,
    bXfer: Txn,
    poolAsset: AssetID,
    aAsset: AssetID,
    bAsset: AssetID
  ): void {
```

Comment: how do you check if the txn is typeof AssetTransferTxn or PayTxn ?